# Is there any way to implement a reverse look-up of the the values in my Flot graph?

Tags: javascript, flot

As the input to my graph, I feed the X and Y values of five points, out of which Flot generates a graph.

For the next step in my program, I want to be able to receive the Y value when I enter an X value. I went through the documentation and did not find anything of substance, I was wondering whether I could get some suggestions as to how to go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `flot.getData()` That will return all your x/y points, and you can find it in  there

```
// Pseudo-code, not tested
function getX(flot, x) {
    var data = flot.getData()[0]; // Get the first series
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) {
        if (data[0] === x) { // first item is x
            return data[1]; // second item is y
        }
    }
}
```

---

I initially thought you wanted to get the point from an x/y coordinate, leaving it here since it could be useful to someone else in the future....

Each flot object has methods called

- plot.c2p = canvasToAxisCoords;
- plot.p2c = axisToCanvasCoords;

They are how you can convert from x,y into coordinates and back

Comment: Note that the tracking example (http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/tracking/index.html) demonstrates how to do exactly this.